# Como usar recursos em Português-BR de Microsoft ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, resources

Eu encontrei esse pacote, mas não sei como usar:

> **Recursos em Português-BR de Microsoft ASP.NET MVC**
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br 
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br/

Como utilizar os recursos deste pacote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta instalar o pacote e definir sua configuração de globalização da seguinte forma (`Web.config`):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
    ...
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Feito isso, as mensagens automáticas do *framework* deverão aparecer em português, incluindo as mensagens de erro.

Lembrando que este pacote traduz apenas uma parte dos recursos. [Uma boa parte está aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pt-br).

Comment: é possível mostrar as mensagens geradas automaticamente nos templates em pt-br ? por exemplo  " @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.FonrecedorID }) "

Comment: Isto é outra coisa, envolvendo [Scaffolding](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+scaffolding). Se precisar, pode fazer outra pergunta.