# Razor linguagem regionalidade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor-pages

estou com um problema no Razor (usando MVC 2.1 .Net Core) ao gerar a tela,
como segue codigo abaixo, esta aparecendo a data correta no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento Local, mas apos o Publish aparece em Inglês nos outros ambientes, teria como forçar a ser em Português?

```
<p>       <label> Data de Nascimento:</label>}
           @Model.DataEmissaoAntecedentes.Value.ToLongDateString()
</p>
```

A pagina é em CSHTML, e é tipada com um Model.

Comment: Configura o Culture de uma  olhda aqui  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137931/como-usar-recursos-em-portugu%C3%AAs-br-de-microsoft-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Olhei o post, mas no meu caso não existe web.config, pois  é DotNetCore 2.1.

Comment: Poderia postar seu model?

Comment: olha a resposta do @Barbetta via code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é no seu modelo usar a `Annotation` `DisplayFormat`, abaixo um exemplo:

```
public class Modelo
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? DataEmissaoAntecedentes{ get; set; }
}
```

Desta forma para usar basta chamar o `@Model.DataEmissaoAntecedentes.Value`, o formato você pode editar no `DataFormatString`

Uma outra alternativa é mudar a cultura da aplicação, dentro do `Startup` no método `Configure` adicione o seguinte código:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou!

```
 var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

Bastou adicionar como nosso Amigo Barbetta, informou!
Obrigado.