# Validação DataAnnotation exibindo mensagem em ingles

Tags: c#, dataannotations

Boa tarde,

No meu sistema fiz as validações com data annotations, localmente as mensagem são exibidas em portugues, quando publico no servidor de hospedagem a mensagem de texto é exibida em ingles, alguem sabe como faço para manter em portugues? Desde já gradeço

Comment: O Windows do servidor está em inglês?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335376/razor-linguagem-regionalidade/335381#335381

Comment: esse exemplo é referente a data e também do .net core, estou usando asp.net MVC

Comment: Outra relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137931/como-usar-recursos-em-portugu%C3%AAs-br-de-microsoft-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece, respondendo de forma simples, porque a configuração do seu IIS local está em português e o seu IIS remoto está em Inglês.

Para mudar essa configuração de globalização do seu IIS você deve adicionar a seguinte linha no seu arquivo **web.config**.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: já possuo essa linha no meu web.config, está da seguinte forma:     <globalization culture="pt-BR" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="pt-BR" />

Comment: Adiciona a propriedade enableClientBasedCulture="false" , testa com 'true' também.

Comment: Nada, já testei com os 2. continua exibindo em ingles

Comment: Cara manda um trecho do data annotation

Comment: estou validando com [StringLength(20)]

Comment: e é retornado o erro: Erro
The field NomeEmpresaAtividade must be a string with a maximum length of 20.

Comment: cara passa o segundo parâmetro, que é a mensagem de erro:
 [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage="Mensagem de erro")], só para ver qual será a saída.

Comment: Valeu, assim deu certo. Obrigado